# While Loop inside While (Java) Battleship Game

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, freeze

I am trying to cycle though the list of ships I am asking the user about. There is already a while loop. After I added the second one on the outside it freezes after one run of the second loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String playerName;
int uInput;
public static String[] names = {"DESTROYER","SUBMARINE","CRUISER","BATTLESHIP","AIRCRAFT"};
public static int[] shipL = {2, 3, 3, 5, 6 };

public static void shipSetup()
{
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
  String input = " ";
  int valid = 0;
  int index = 0;
  while(index != 4){
    while (valid !=3){
      System.out.println("Place " + names[index] + " ("+ shipL[index]+ " spaces - Format: Coordinate #1, Coordinate #2, Direction)");
      input = sc.nextLine();
      String[] inputArray;
      inputArray = input.split(",");
      //3 values errors
      if(inputArray.length != 3){System.out.println("ERROR:Invalid Direction");continue;}
        try{
          char z = inputArray[2].charAt(0);
          int x = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[0]);
          int y = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[1]);
          //resets loop
          valid = 0;
          //Input direction errors
          if(z != 'V' && z != 'H'){
            System.out.println("ERROR:Invalid Direction - Vertical|V| or Horizontal|H|");
          }
          else{
            ++valid;
          }
          //Input cord errors
          if(x > 9 || x < 0){
            System.out.println("ERROR:Invalid Coordinate - Coordinate must be 1 - 9");
          }
          else{
            ++valid;
          }
          if(y > 9 || y < 0){
            System.out.println("ERROR:Invalid Coordinate - Coordinate must be 1 - 9");
          }
          else{
            ++valid;
          }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
          System.out.println("ERROR: Coordinate are numbers dumbASS");
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: PLEASE use some formatting!

Comment: What do you mean it freezes? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 4):

It means that the program flow enters every `else` statement, increases `valid` to 3, and then continues to loop infinitely inside the outer `while(index != 4)` loop.

Put an attention that the `index` value checked in outer `while` condition is never edited, therefore it's always equals to initial 0. That's why your program passes the outer while loop test infinitely, and never exits it.